# Sort after a specific date php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple code that collects data from my mysql database:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dato ASC") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($get)) {
while($show = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {

}
} else {
echo "No results";
}
```

But the list is now over 200 items, and i would like to sort them on dates, så that i have forexample.

```
26/08-2015
1. line
2. line
3. line
4. line

27/08-2015
5. line
6. line
7. line
```

Instead of

```
1. line
2. line
3. line
4. line
5. line
6. line
7. line
```

Which i get now

The date i sort after is a mktime date.

```
$dato = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
```

Comment: please explain it bit more !

Comment: The point is to make it more foreseeable, so i dont get one long list with anything right after each other, but spliited up in dates, so i have, as i wrote, 26/08-2015 and then all the results from that day, then 2 line breaks, then 27/08-2015 and then all the results from that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(`date`)) as dt, t.* FROM table t ORDER BY 1") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($get)) {
    $prevDT = "";
    while($show = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
        if (strlen($prevDT) < 0 || strcmp($prevDT, $show['dt']) != 0){
            echo("<br />");
            echo($show['dt']."<br />");
            $prevDT = $show['dt'];
        }
        echo($show['field']."<br />");
    }
} else {
    echo "No results";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly that type of code i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try this with where condition

```
$dato = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > $dato ORDER BY date ASC") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($get)) {
    while($show = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {

    }
} else {
    echo "No results";
}
```

Comment: but that only shows the ones with a date greater than today? thats not the point, the point is to make it more foreseeable, so i dont get one long list with anything right after each other, but spliited up in dates, so i have, as i wrote, 26/08-2015 and then all the results from that day, then 2 line breaks, then 27/08-2015 and then all the results from that day.

Comment: @RasmusKjeldsen, I think you should try to do it at application side !

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$currentDate = null;
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dato ASC") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($get)) {
while($show = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
if($currentDate != $show['dato'])
     echo "<BR><BR>";
$currentDate = $show['dato'];
}
} else {
echo "No results";
}
```